# Wrong Transition Context

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `ContainerViewController` which contains a `ChildViewController`. Now I would like to present with my `ChildViewController` a `ModalViewController` using a custom transition.

The problem is that in my `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` the method

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {}
```

provides `ContainerViewController` as the `presenting` constant.

Is there a way to get `ChildViewController` as the presenting constant?

Thank you!